# how to store bigdecimal in firestore in Android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, bigdecimal

I am trying to insert object into Firestore using Android Studio, it gives an error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Unsupported type: java.math.BigDecimal
```

[image: error message]

How can I insert BigDecimal into Firestore?

Answer (score 1):

Check Firestore's [supported types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). If you need anything else, convert to a supported type, then convert back when you read. Typically, you'd use `String` for `BigDecimal`. If you need comparisons, zero-pad to your theoretical maximum, or store in another field as `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (in Kotlin):

```
class Model() {

    @get:PropertyName("value") 
    @set:PropertyName("value")
    var firestoreValue: String = "0"

    var value: BigDecimal
        @Exclude get() = firestoreValue.toBigDecimal()
        @Exclude set(value) { firestoreValue = value.toPlainString() }
}
```

Haven't found a better solution so far. Would be nice if it was possible to implement converters (like TypeAdapters for Gson) for unsupported types.